# Como retornar um array em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função pra fazer o upload de imagens e por enquanto o array imgs tá indo pro escopo global, mas eu queria que essa função pudesse retornar esse array:

```
function loadImages () {
    imgs = [];
    for (var i in arguments) {
        var start = arguments[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        var end = arguments[i].indexOf(".");
        var name = arguments[i].substring(start, end);
        imgs[name] = new Image();
        imgs[name].src = arguments[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: depois do for adicione: return imgs;

Comment: Consegui resolver mudando no começo para **var imgs = new Object()** e no final o **return imgs**

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de adicionar alguns pontos:

```
function loadImages () {
    let imgs = []; // se usar let não vai alterar nenhum imgs[] fora desse escopo

    // forEach percorre um array com o intuito de gerar side-effects
    // se arguments for um array-like, tem que converter com o  Array.from()
    // mas vou assumir que não é:
    arguments.forEach(x => {
        // regex que seleciona o que estiver entre o ultimo / e . 
        var name = x.match(/(.*)\/(.*)\./).pop(); 
        imgs[name] = new Image();
        imgs[name].src = x;
    });

    return imgs; //retorna o imgs como perguntado
}
```